# Issues conducting a simple read on a table

Tags: supabase

I apologize if this is a simple/obvious fix, but currently I'm trying to read from a simple table from within a session; I'm able to insert properly, and there are two records in the table.

```
const fetchExercises = async () => {
        if(session){
            try {
                let {data: exercises, error} = await supabase
                    .from('exercises')
                    .select('*')
                    .eq('created_by', session.user.id.toString())

                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }

                console.log('************ AFTER GETTING EXERCISES *************')
                console.log(exercises)
                return (exercises)
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', e);
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log('User does not have a session active')
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (session) {
            fetchExercises()
                .then(exercises => {
                if (exercises) {
                    setExerciseList(exercises as ExerciseType[]);
                }
            });
        }
    }, []);
```

But my only response is

```
LOG  ************ AFTER GETTING EXERCISES *************
LOG  []
```

I double checked, the created by in my table and the session.user.id match exactly, and here's a picture of the table: [image]

When I was reading the API docs it says to follow this convention:

```
let { data: exercises, error } = await supabase
  .from('exercises')
  .select('*')
```

When printed the API's Response all I got was:

```
API Response: {"count": null, "data": [], "error": null, "status": 200, "statusText": ""}
```

Since the API response is 200 it tells me that my issue isn't anything with authentication or else I wouldn't get a 200.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: This is likely due to missing/incorrect RLS policies: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security